# Spring Batch Retry using Remote Partitioning and Thread Pool Executor trying to process same record twice

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a spring-batch service using remote partitioning and a chunk size of 10. If an item in a chunk fails, there is a retry limit of 3. I am using thread pool executor.
I observed that during Retry, a forkjoinpool worker 0 is being spawned and that processes the records in the failed chunk. Other than that, the thread where the chunk had originally failed also tries to process the records in the chunk simultaneously. As the record was already processed by the fork join pool, the processor is returning a null and thus the filter count in the batch step execution table gets updated instead of the write count. How to prevent multiple processing of the same record in the failed chunk, if it has successfully been executed by another thread.

Answer (score 0):

> How to prevent multiple processing of the same record in the failed chunk, if it has successfully been executed by another thread.

This means the same item can be processed by two different threads, which should not be the case. Each partition should be a distinct data set so that each worker processes distinct items. Other than that, your item processor should be idempotent in a fault tolerant step, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/processor.html#faultTolerant